# for two independent exponential distributions, the product is gamma, proof by integration

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

> If I am correct, the product of the pdfs of two independent
>  exponential law of parameter $\lambda$ should give the pdf of the
>  gamma function.
>  Hereinafter, $X,Y \sim$ exponential law of parameter $\lambda$,
>  independent. 
>  However, I faced that problem :
>  $P(X+Y \leq s ) = \int_0^s \lambda ^2 u e^{- \lambda u } du$ 
>  which is the cumulative distribution function of a gamma rv.
>  On the other hand : 
> \begin{align}P(X\leq x ) P( Y \leq y)=\int_0^x\int_0^y\lambda^2e^{-\lambda  (u+v) } du dv  \end{align}
>  How do you make the "$u$" appear in front of the exponential, and get
>  rid of the integral ? A substitution didn't help me on that one.

---

Sorry I was perhaps totally unclear. So here is the original problem

Let $X,Y,Z$  be three exponential random variables independants.

I want to compute

$$ P( X < Y+Z ) $$

A first way to see that, is saying that $Y+ Z$ is Gamma. Thus:
$$
\begin{align}
P(X < Y + Z ) = \int_0^{\infty} P(X < \gamma ) f_{\Gamma} (\gamma) d\gamma  \\ 
= \int_0^{\infty} [ 1 - \exp( - \lambda \gamma ) ] \cdot \lambda^2 \gamma e^{- \lambda \gamma } \cdot  d \gamma
\end{align}
$$
on the other hand, I rewrite the expression as:

$$
\begin{align}
P(X < Y + Z ) = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}  P(X < y + z ) f_{\epsilon } (y) f_{\epsilon } (z) dy dz \\
= \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} [ 1 - \exp( - \lambda (y + z ) ] \cdot \lambda^2 [ e^{ - \lambda (y + z ) } ] \cdot dy dz
\end{align}
$$

Those two expressions should be equal, (and they are for my exercice at the end I get the good result). But I am surprised how

$\lambda^2 [ e^{ - \lambda (y + z ) } ]  $ is transformed into $\lambda^2 \gamma e^{- \lambda \gamma }$. How come?

Comment: How are these two integrals related?

Comment: it seems to me that they are the same, even though the second has two variables. As mentionned, they should be both the CDF of a gamma distribution

Comment: no $(X,Y)$ does not follow a gamma distribution. It is not even a random variable, but rather a random vector, so it's distribution is two-dimensional.

Comment: The pdf of a sum of independent variables is the convolution of the density functions and not the product.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen I changed the question, to make it more understandable

Comment: @d.k.o. I hope this is now clear. Here is the situation I faced and didn't get what happenned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a fundamental misconception of the relationship between functions of random variables, and functions of their densities.

When I say $X$ and $Y$ are IID exponential random variables, say each with density $$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, \quad f_Y(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y},$$ when I multiply the densities together, you get a **joint density** on a quadrant of $\mathbb R^2$ $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \lambda e^{-\lambda y},$$ for **ordered pairs** of positive reals $(x,y)$.  This is a bivariate distribution and is not gamma or anything of that sort.

However, if I take the sum of the random variables $X + Y$, I obtain a new univariate random variable, say $W = X + Y$, whose support is on the positive reals and is Gamma distributed with shape $2$ and rate $\lambda$:  $$f_W(w) = \lambda^2 w e^{-\lambda w}.$$  When I add random variables together, I get another random variable of the same dimension as their summands, just like when I add $2 + 3$ I do not get a vector, but a scalar; and when I add $(3,4) + (2,1)$ I don't get a scalar, I get an ordered pair.

---

To address your computation for the original question, $\Pr[X < Y + Z]$, both methods are correct and equivalent but not in the way that you are conceptualizing it.  This becomes apparent if you write out the statement precisely as follows.  Let $W = Y + Z \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(2,\lambda)$ as stated above.  Then $\Pr[X < Y + Z] = \Pr[X < W]$ and the first method gives $$\Pr[X < W] = \int_{w=0}^\infty \Pr[X < w \mid W = w]f_W(w) \, dw \\
= \int_{w=0}^\infty (1 - e^{-\lambda w})\lambda^2 w e^{-\lambda w} \, dw.$$  The second statement is $$\Pr[X < Y + Z] = \int_{y=0}^\infty \int_{z=0}^\infty \Pr[X < Y + Z \mid (Y,Z) = (y,z)] f_{Y,Z}(y,z) \, dy \, dz \\ = \int_{y=0}^\infty \int_{z=0}^\infty (1 - e^{-\lambda (y+z)}) \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \lambda e^{-\lambda z} \, dy \, dz.$$  They integrate to the same result but the integrands are different and they are not comparable, because the variables of integration are not the same.  In particular, $w$ is neither $y$ nor $z$, so just because the limits of integration are $(0, \infty)$, you can't assume the single integral in the first method represents one of the two integrals in the second.

Now, you can perform the convolution of $f_Y$ and $f_Z$ to *prove* that $W = Y + Z$ has the density that we claim it does, but this is not the point of your question.